# JavaScript error with Cascading Dropdowns

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, javascript, dropdown, cascading

Many similar questions have been asked but none seem to work.

I have Sharepoint 2010 and I have jquery-1.9.1.min and jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min loaded into my parent site's Shared Documents.  It seems to be loading them properly.

I've tried the most simplistic example and I'm still get the following error.
*"Message: 'childColumnStatic' is undefined"*

Here is the code I added into the header.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Franchising/Shared%20Documents/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Franchising/Shared%20Documents/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList: "Product",
            relationshipListParentColumn: "Group",
            relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
            parentColumn: "Group",
            childColumn: "Product",
            debug: true
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

I created the following tables.
Parent List: Group
1 Column: Title(single line Text)

Child List: Product
2 Columns:Title(Single line text), Group(Lookup of Parent list)

Main List: Sample
3 Columns: Title(Single line text), Group(Lookup to Parent List), Product(Lookup to Child List)

I have been referencing this also. [http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns)

Thanks you for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their site apparently the version of jQuery you are using does not work with SPServices...

"2013-02-05 - SPServices will *not* work with jQuery 1.9.1 due to a bug in that release."

[SPServices on codeplex](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the latest jQuery versions, you can use this utility i just released that doesn't need SPServices anymore.

You can use this utility on webpart pages, aspx pages and forms also.

The link for more details : http://sylvainlancien.blogspot.fr/2013/11/slnspcascadingdropdown-jquery-cascade.html

Comment: A note for 2013 peeps reading this, it isn't fully 2013 compatible please check here for other things to take into consideration http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68661/how-to-add-jquery-script-to-a-custom-visual-webpart/83063#83063